# Drupal 8 select field in block

Tags: javascript, drupal-modules, drupal-8

Hi I have this code in a module I'm creating that I output in a function in the controller class:

```
$output ="
        <span id="dateofshow"> Date of Show:<select id="showdate" class="js-
    showtimes-select Showtimes-select">'
        <option value="2017-07-07">Sat, Jul  7</option>
        <option value="2017-07-08">Sat, Jul  8</option>
        <option value="2017-07-09">Sat, Jul  9</option>
        etc...
        </select></span>"
return output;
```

It displays correctly when I output it its its own page however when I turn it into a block it gets stripped out and looks like this:

```
<span id="dateofshow"> Date of Show: Fri, Jul  7Sat, Jul  8Sun, Jul  9Mon, Jul  10Tue, Jul  11Wed, Jul  12Thu, Jul  13Fri, Jul  14Sat, Jul  15Sun, Jul  16Mon, Jul  17Tue, Jul  18Wed, Jul  19Thu, Jul  20Wed, Jul  26Thu, Jul  27Wed, Aug  2Thu, Aug  3Wed, Aug  9Thu, Aug  10Fri, Aug  25Sat, Aug  26Sun, Aug  27Mon, Aug  28Tue, Aug  29Wed, Aug  30Thu, Aug  31</span>
```

Also `style="display: block;"` tags gets stripped out in block form as well in the same function in this code:

```
<div id="2017-07-07" class="js-showtimes-date" style="display: block;">
```

Whats the correct way to do this in Drupal 8?

**Update:** Here is the code I'm using with some irrelevant parts cut out:

tlistingcontroller.php

```
namespace Drupal\ttimes\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use \DateTime;

class tlistingsController 
{
  public function buildtimes(){
  $output = "";

xmlpath = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath(file_default_scheme() . "://").'/x/'.'siteId.xml';
$schedResult = simplexml_load_file($xmlpath);

  $output .= <span id="dofshow"> Date of Show: <select id="showd" class="js-showtimes-select Showtimes-select">';
  foreach($schedResult->xpath('//EBDates/EBDate') as $dates){
            $dateformat = date_format ( new DateTime($dates->BDate) , 'D, M  j');
            $output .= '<option value="'. $dates->BDate . '">'. $dateformat . '</option>';
  $output .= '</select></span>';
  return $output;
}
public function tlistings_page() {  //This is what gets called in the .routing.yml file
    return array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#attached' => array(
        'library' => array(
          'tlisting/global',),),
      '#markup' => $this->buildtimes(),
    );  
    }
}
```

I updated it since I first posted it by adding a library with some css and js so I could do that.  The function reads and xml file then outputs data from it and part of the data is dates that it extracts and puts into select and options tags. How can use a select form but put in the same place it currently is with this extracted data from the function?

Comment: show us your code ?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons drupal strips out html and inline styles. The better way ist to work with the form API and implement the class FormBase.

[FormAPI Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/introduction-to-form-api)

You should also have a look at this [tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/add-a-form-to-the-block-configuration)

Comment: Thanks I'm still new to Drupal 8 development coming from earlier versions. I'll read up on it.  I found out i could use '#allowed_tags' => ['option', 'select', 'a', 'div'], in the render away to skirt the issue but I I want learn the drupal way to do it. I will study this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the span you could use prefix and suffix:

```
$options['2017-07-07'] = 'Sat, Jul  7';
$options['2017-07-08'] = 'Sat, Jul  8';
$options['2017-07-09'] = 'Sat, Jul  9';

$form['showdate'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => $options,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#title' => $this->t('Date of Show:'),
  '#prefix' => '<span id="dateofshow">',
  '#suffix' => '</span>');
```

As far as I understand you must use attributes on a render array to get inline styles to output.

```
  $form['showdate'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => $options,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#title' => $this->t('Date of Show:'),
  '#prefix' => '<span id="dateofshow">',
  '#suffix' => '</span>',
  '#attributes' => array ('style' => 'display: block;'));
```

My suggestion is not to fight the markup that Drupal outputs but rather work with it. I would be happy to expand if you provide some more information about what you are trying to achieve.

**UPDATE:**
Here is some more code that might help you in light of your update. I have not tested this.

```
$xmlpath = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath(file_default_scheme() . "://").'/x/'.'siteId.xml';
  $schedResult = simplexml_load_file($xmlpath);
  $options = array();
  foreach($schedResult->xpath('//EBDates/EBDate') as $dates)
  {
    $options[$dates->BDate] = date_format ( new DateTime($dates->BDate) , 'D, M  j');
  }
  $form['showdate'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#title' => $this->t('Date of Show:'),
    '#attributes' => array (
      'class' => array(
        'js-showtimes-select',
        'Showtimes-select')));
```

Comment: I read a little bit about creating forms this way but the part I don't understand is how to return the form in the middle of the output from my function. Also my function has data from an xml file that populates the form how would I get that in there as well? I updated my original post with more code on what I'm doing.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks i'll fix that.

Comment: Have added another example that may be helpful. @vishwa is correct in regards to wrapping things in spans. As I suggested in my original answer, try to work with the Drupal markup, not against it and your life will be easier, I say this from experience :S